# Clip an SVG Element to itself

Tags: svg

Whats the easiest and in terms of DOM elements most lightweight way to clip an SVGElement to itself in addition to an already existing clippath?

```
<path d="M 0 0 L 500 0 L 500 500 L 0 500 Z" clip-path="url(#existing-clippath)"/>
```

My current solution looks like this but seems quite cumbersome

```
<clippath id="element-itself">
  <path d="M 0 0 L 500 0 L 500 500 L 0 500 Z"></path>
</clippath>
<g clip-path="url(#element-itself)">
  <path d="M 0 0 L 500 0 L 500 500 L 0 500 Z" clip-path="url(#existing-clippath)"/>
</g>
```

#### Edit

Using a `<use>` element seems like a good choice, as pointed out by Robert Longson:

```
<clippath id="element-itself">
  <use xlink:href="#element">
</clippath>
<g clip-path="url(#element-itself)">
  <path id="element" d="M 0 0 L 500 0 L 500 500 L 0 500 Z"
        clip-path="url(#existing-clippath)"/>
</g>
```

Is there any easier/shorter way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the point of clipping to yourself is but you could clip to a `<use>` element that points to the original element which would avoid repeating the path.

Comment: The point is stroking an already clipped element only to its inside.

Comment: On a sidenote, addition/removal of the `path` element via javascript leads to bugs in internet explorers and webkits and only works the way expected in firefox and old operas :(